# xmlhttprequest is not defined node js

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, node.js

Где проблема?

```js
    // 1. Создаём новый объект XMLHttpRequest
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // 2. Конфигурируем его: GET-запрос на URL 'phones.json'
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5', false);

    // 3. Отсылаем запрос
    xhr.send();

    // 4. Если код ответа сервера не 200, то это ошибка
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      // обработать ошибку
      console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
    } else {
      // вывести результат
      console.log( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`XMLHttpRequest` не поставляется по умолчанию в Node.js. [Его](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) нужно установить с помощью `npm`. По мотивам [данного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found).

При использовании нужно не забыть про `require`:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: У меня он установлен. Версия 3.10.3. Может его как-то нужно подключить?

Comment: @VaniaKycher судя по [странице плагина](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest), последняя версия плагина 1.8.0. Где вы взяли 3.10.3?

Comment: @VaniaKycher добавил в ответ пример его использования: возможно, вы упустили первую строку.

Comment: Хах..теперь require is not defined.
Модуль require установлен - версия 2.4.20

Comment: @VaniaKycher вы ведь на сервере запускаете этот скрипт, а не в браузере?

Comment: Да. То что консоль мне выдает - то вам и пишу)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42376/discussion-between-vania-kycher-and-regent).